# How to query an Xml Document using a SP and populate an ASP DropDownList from code-behind?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml

Given the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <lfSpec1ForLoc>
        <a href="/spec.aspx?id=20" title="AI">AI</a>
    </lfSpec1ForLoc>
    <lfSpec2ForLoc />
    <lfSpec3ForLoc />
    <lfSpec4ForLoc />
    <lfSpec5ForLoc />
    <lfSpec6ForLoc />
    <lfSpec7ForLoc />
    <lfSpec8ForLoc />
    <lfSpec9ForLoc />
    <lfSpec10ForLoc />
</root>
```

My URL is: `www.mypage.com/off.aspx?id=12`

I have the following Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySP]
(
@LstrID varchar(200), -- 12 {from the query string in the above URL}
)

AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec1ForLoc/a') AS [Spec1]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec2ForLoc/a') AS [Spec2]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec3ForLoc/a') AS [Spec3]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec4ForLoc/a') AS [Spec4]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec5ForLoc/a') AS [Spec5]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec6ForLoc/a') AS [Spec6]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec7ForLoc/a') AS [Spec7]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec8ForLoc/a') AS [Spec8]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec9ForLoc/a') AS [Spec9]
        , CAST ([con] AS XML).query('/root/lfSpec10ForLoc/a') AS [Spec10]
    FROM
        [myDB1].[dbo].[con]
    WHERE
        [folder_id] = 106
        AND 
        [content_id] = '%' + Lstr + '%'
END
```

The result from the SP is:

```
Spec1                                           Spec2                                       Spec3   Spec4   Spec5   Spec6   Spec7   Spec8   Spec9   Spec10
<a href="/spe.aspx?id=1" title="AI">AI</a>      <a href="/spe.aspx?id=5" title="QW">QW</a>
```

I would like to populate the below dropdownlist:

```
<ASP:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl1"></ASP:DropDownList>
```

So the HTML output is as follow:

```
<SELECT>
    <option value="/spe.aspx?id=1">AI</option>
    <option value="/spe.aspx?id=5">QW</option>
</SELECT>
```

What is the best way to achieve the populating the dropdownlist after executing the SP?

Comment: Create a loop that iterates through the 2nd row that is returned, parse out the value and the text from each row, and add a new item to the dropdown list with the value and text.

Comment: @TonyHinkle Possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your `PROC` to make better usage of Xquery and the xml parsing capabilities of Sql Server.

What you can do from your PROC is project a table of `(URL, Title)` pairs from your the xml Records in your table with a query as simple as:

```
SELECT Nodes.node.value('(a/@href)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS URL,
       Nodes.node.value('(a/@title)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Title
FROM 
(
  SELECT CAST(con.con AS XML) AS con,
    folder_id,
    content_id
    FROM con
) x
CROSS APPLY x.Con.nodes('/root/*[a]') as Nodes(node)
WHERE
[folder_id] = 106
AND 
[content_id] LIKE '%' + @LstrID + '%';
```

The `/root/*[a]` will navigate all `lfSpecxForLoc` nodes (irrespective of name), and filter just those with an `a` child element, thus avoiding the need to filter out nulls. Also, by projecting the elements as individual rows, you won't need to scrape out 10 explicit columns - there will be as many rows as there are data.

Here's a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20bdb/4) of the resulting table projected by the above query.

From here, it is a simple task to pull the resultset into an ADO data reader or bind this to your drop down list (e.g. set the `.DataSource` to the data reader, and call `.DataBind()` on the `DropDownList`).

Comment: The `con` column is of type `ntext`, So i get the following error: `Msg 9506, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.`

Comment: I've adjusted the query with a CAST to XML. AFAIK you'll need a wrapping derived table in order to do the `CROSS APPLY`.